# Azure OpenaAI GPT-4 Review version cannot be found in the list of models

Tags: azure-openai, gpt-4

I received an email on 18 April confirming that I have been onboarded to the Azure OpenAI Service GPT-4 Preview, but GPT-4 Review version cannot be found in the list of OpenAI models and GPT-4 cannot be deployed, Whether my resource group choice is Eastern US or South Central US.

I would be grateful if any guru could help me.

I should have used a variety of methods and I am a pay-as-you-go subscriber.